# htaccess: upload a directory only to a url series

Tags: .htaccess, vbulletin

Anyone know how to redirect with `.htaccess` all the URLs of the form:

- `www.example.com/showthread.php(any content)` to
- `www.example.com/forum/showthread.php(same content)`

I just want it to happen in this type of URL, there are other URL that I do not want to be modified.

Comment: What is `(any content)`? Are you referring to a query string (starting with a `?`) or path info (starting with a slash)? What do you mean by "upload" in your question title? This doesn't appear to relate to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `(any content)` is referring to a query string (starting with a `?`). You can do something like the following using mod_rewrite in your root `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^showthread\.php$ /forum/$0 [R=302,L]
```

This would need to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file.

This will redirect a URL of the form `/showthread.php?<something>` to `/forum/showthread.php?<something>`.

`$0` is a backreference to the entire URL-path that is matched. The query string is automatically copied through to the target URL.

This is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Change to a 301 if this intended to be permanent - but only after you have confirmed it's working OK.